# playing sound in Python with the ability to cut it off mid-play

Tags: python, audio, omxplayer

I am writing a bit of python code that plays a sound file (MP3 or the equivalent) and should cut that sound off if the user strikes a (hardware) button that is wired into the system. This will be on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. The libraries I’ve used historically for playing sound all play to completion. The closest approach I can think of would be using an external sound player (OMXplayer perhaps) and then searching for and killing its process if the button is pressed, but this feels inelegant. Can anybody suggest a better approach?

Comment: @Ann Zen, the OP is on  ̶R̶a̶s̶p̶b̶i̶a̶n̶  the Raspberry Pi OS. `Winsound` is Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) you could simply check a flag before writing each buffer to the stream, and if the audio should stop, fade out the current buffer and then either continue the stream with silence (write 0's) or stop the stream and exit the program. This could be easily be achieved with a latency of ~1/10s after button press.

You would also need to create a UI thread in the application to handle commands since the stopping flag is switched on user input.